# Disable time slots in fullcalendar plugin

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I was using a fullcalendar plugin for my booking system. How can I disable the day and time in the calendar so that the user cannot book an event in that certain day and time? The code I've tried so far is below, but it currently doesn't work.

```
disableDate:function(date)
{
   if(options.disableDates) {
      var disabled_dates = options.disableDates
      var string_date = formatDate(date,"MM-dd-yyyy")
      if (disabled_dates.indexOf(string_date) > -1 )
      {
         return true
      }
   }
   return false
}
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for us to be able to help you. Please post code.

Comment: disableDate:function(date) {
            if(options.disableDates){
                var disabled_dates = options.disableDates
                var string_date = formatDate(date,"MM-dd-yyyy")
           
                if (disabled_dates.indexOf(string_date) > -1 ){
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
            
        },                                 I've tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: This should be in the body of the question itself; it's easier to read, plus it avoids the necessity of having to read through comments section to see the full details of the question. Please also clarify what you mean by "doesn't work."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Background Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) to accomplish this. In [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEXQkN) I use some of the code from the [FullCalendar Background Events Demo](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/background-events.html) to set background events that will not allow certain events to be placed in that spot.

```
// red areas where no events can be dropped
{
    start: '2016-08-24',
    end: '2016-08-28',
    overlap: false,
    rendering: 'background',
    color: '#ff9f89'
}
```

Check out the week view where you can also set constraints where only specified events can be placed in the Background Events.

```
{
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-08-13T11:00:00',
    constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
    color: '#257e4a'
},
{
    id: 'availableForMeeting',
    start: '2016-08-11T10:00:00',
    end: '2016-08-11T16:00:00',
    rendering: 'background'
}
```

Comment: thanks Ryan89 it has red areas now  but I can still click in the red areas.

Comment: @kuzo What do you mean? Clicking an area does nothing unless you have code that does something on click, which should then be included in your question. The code I provided will prevent events from being dragged into specified areas like your question asks. Any additional details need to be included in your question, I cannot guess how your application works.

Comment: @Ryan89I wanted to disable a certain day so that the users can't click on that day.

Comment: @kuzo Yes but you need to explain what your application does when a user click on a day, Full Calendar itself does nothing when a user clicks on a day unless you tell it otherwise. You should edit your question with your code. There is no more help I can offer with what you have currently provided.